# Windows Command To List Users That Are Not Able To Change Their Password and Users That Have Password Expire Set To Never

Tags: windows, powershell, command

Using PowerShell, I would like to display users that are not able to change their own password.

If I run the command below:

```
get-localuser | select Name,UserMayChangePassword
```

I see this output:

```
Name               UserMayChangePassword
----               ---------------------
Administrator                       True
Test                               False
```

I crafted the command below to capture users that have the setting set to False, however, this does not seem to work:

```
get-localuser |  Where-Object { $_.UserMayChangePassword -eq "False" }
```

Seprately, I would also like to check users that do not have a password expiry, so far I was able to craft this command which does not work:

```
get-localuser | Where-Object { $_.PasswordExpires -ne ''}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this...

```
Get-LocalUser | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name               UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----               --------------------- ---------------      
Administrator                       True                      
DefaultAccount                      True                      
Guest                              False                      
TestUser                           False 5/20/2021 11:43:52 AM
WDAGUtilityAccount                  True 5/19/2021 12:49:19 PM
#>


Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object -Property UserMayChangePassword -ne 'True' | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires

# Results
<#
Name     UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----     --------------------- ---------------      
Guest                    False                      
TestUser                 False 5/20/2021 11:43:52 AM
#>


Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object -Property PasswordExpires -NE $null |  
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name               UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----               --------------------- ---------------      
TestUser                           False 5/20/2021 11:43:52 AM
WDAGUtilityAccount                  True 5/19/2021 12:49:19 PM
#>


Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object -Property PasswordExpires -EQ $null |  
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name           UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires
----           --------------------- ---------------
Administrator                   True                
DefaultAccount                  True                
Guest                          False 
#>
```

You don't really need the braces `{}` or the `$PSItem` (aka `$_`), for your direct use case.  Though you could.

```
Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object {$_.UserMayChangePassword -eq 'True'} | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name               UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----               --------------------- ---------------      
Administrator                       True                      
DefaultAccount                      True                      
WDAGUtilityAccount                  True 5/19/2021 12:49:19 PM
#>



Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object {$_.UserMayChangePassword -ne 'True'} | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name     UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----     --------------------- ---------------      
Guest                    False                      
TestUser                 False 5/20/2021 11:43:52 AM
#>



Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object {$_.PasswordExpires -ne $null} | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name               UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires      
----               --------------------- ---------------      
TestUser                           False 5/20/2021 11:43:52 AM
WDAGUtilityAccount                  True 5/19/2021 12:49:19 PM
#>



Get-LocalUser | 
Where-Object {$_.PasswordExpires -eq $null} | 
Select-Object -Property Name, UserMayChangePassword, PasswordExpires
# Results
<#
Name           UserMayChangePassword PasswordExpires
----           --------------------- ---------------
Administrator                   True                
DefaultAccount                  True                
Guest                          False  
#>
```